# PLSQL & Oracle - Join 2 tables and only return based on latest date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

this is a question for plsql & oracles. I am new to this. Please help!

I have 2 tables: Table A and Table B

```
Table A: ID, Date
Table B: Name, Address
```

How do I do a join between 2 tables and then have it just return based on latest date. Also, it will be based on specified ID in a list.

My current query returns this:

```
1 | 1/1/2013 | Apple | 123 Malcolm
1 | 1/2/2013 | Apple | 123 Malcolm
1 | 1/3/2013 | Apple | 123 Malcolm
3 | 1/1/2013 | Orange| 124 Malcolm
3 | 1/2/2013 | Orange| 124 Malcolm
```

How do I get it to return just:

```
1 | 1/3/2013 | Apple | 123 Malcolm
3 | 1/2/2013 | Orange| 124 Malcolm

select unique(ID), a.Date, b.Name, b.Address
from tableA a
join tableB b
on a.ID = b.ID
where a.Date > TO_DATE('12/31/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and a.ID in ('1', '3')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `group` your result set. Also you need an aggregat function, in this case `MAX()`

This should work:

```
select unique(ID), MAX(a.Date), b.Name, b.Address
from tableA a
join tableB b
on a.ID = b.ID
where a.Date > TO_DATE('12/31/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and a.ID in ('1', '3')
group by ID, b.Name, b.Address
```

You can read up on those methods and more over at http://www.w3schools.com/sql

Link to the `GROUP BY` explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Link to the `MAX()` explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

Comment: Far simpler than I was thinking.

Comment: @xQbert heh, I looked at your example and thought 'well, that looks interesting'. I never knew you could do a `select` inside a `JOIN`...wait, oh you `join` the result of the `select` statement. That's an interesting thing to do.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I was thinking that there was going to be a problem with grouping which would prevent this from working.  Then I saw yours and said; DUH there is no problem with the grouping as the IDs are duplicated in table A.  IF we had to get a UNIQUE ID, my approach works whereas this may not.

Comment: @xQbert true on that. But in that case the database would offend the first normal form.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of ways to do this:

This is one.  It gets a subset of max dates by the ID and then joins it into what you have already thereby limiting to the max of each group.

```
Select A.ID, A.Date, B.Name, B.Address
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN (Select max(date) maxDate, ID from A group by ID) C
 on C.ID=A.ID and C.MaxDate = A.Date
WHERE
A.ID IN ('1','3')
```

Answer (score 1):

This way uses analytics:

```
select a_id,
       a_date,
       b_name,
       b_address
from (
select a.id   as a_id,
       a.date as a_date,
       b.name as b_name,
       b.address as b_address,
       rank() over (partition by a.name_id
                        order by a.date desc) as rnk
from a inner join b on a.id=b.id
 where a.id in ('1','3') and 
       a.date > to_date('12/31/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
)
where rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fast and simple solution. I assume that ID and Date in TableA form the PK, so are indexed. The subquery finds the Max date for the specified ID and does it quickly due to the index. That record is then used to join to TableB. I use this format all the time when looking through a sequence of dates to find the latest (Max), or earliest (Min). You'll find it acceptably fast even if TableA is very large.

```
with
TableA as (
  select 1 id, date '2013-01-01' selected from dual union all
  select 1, date '2013-01-02'from dual union all
  select 1, date '2013-01-03'from dual union all
  select 3, date '2013-01-01' from dual union all
  select 3, date '2013-01-02' from dual
),
TableB as (
  select 1 id, 'Apple' name, '123 Malcolm' addr from dual union all
  select 3, 'Orange', '124 Malcolm' from dual
)
-- Here is the query:
select *
from   TableB b
join   TableA a
  on   a.id = b.id
   and a.selected =(
         select Max( selected )
         from   TableA
         where  id = a.id
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Analytical functions like RANK() will be the best option.